# scrollTop() returns [object Object]

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am trying to create a simple jQuery code to add a class to each 'selector' element when scrolling over. I need the offsetParent because sometimes this 'selector' is inside many div items.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    $('.selector').each(function () {
         var top = $(window).scrollTop();
         var element = $(this).offsetParent().scrollTop();
         if ( top > element ) {
             $(this).addClass('run');
         }
         console.log( element + ' ' +top );
     });
});
```

jsfiddle 
    http://jsfiddle.net/uT7Cu/

Comment: where is `animates` defined and why are you wrapping `top` with `$()`?

Comment: check again, I edited.

Comment: for your update: `element` is defined within the `each` callback, so it is out of scope by the time you try to log it, and `top` looks like it might be getting clobbered by the loop (though I'm not sure; it shouldn't). Please provide a SSCCE (jsfiddle is a good site to use).

Comment: ah, no, `top` is also going out of scope, because it's local to the scroll callback function. You should try logging within the function itself, instead of writing it in the console later.

Comment: added jsfiddle, it's adding run class to all selectors but not those currently scrolled to, their scroll is always 0.

Comment: Maybe this is what you intended: http://jsfiddle.net/uT7Cu/1/ (`scrollTop` is for elements which scroll; you just want `offset().top`). I also changed the code to be a little bit more efficient.

Comment: Yea, thanks man, post this and will mark your answer :)